# Scraping Instagram data using google spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets, instagram

I need data like bio, and number of posts from public Instagram account using google spreadsheet. I'm able to extract number of followers and following. Can you help ?

Comment: there are services that will export instagram data to csv, which u can open in google spreadsheet: http://blog.picodash.com/post/152986320610/download-instagram-metadata-to-spreadsheet

Comment: Thank You @krisrak. Need real-time data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This formula is going to look really complicated but really all it is - is an importxml formula to pull in the data from the "script" section which has the pieces you want... then using a bunch of regexreplace/extract functions I clean up the data into a readable format:

take this public page for example: http://www.instagram.com/salesforce/

Then in B1 or C1 enter this:

```
=iferror(arrayformula(regexreplace({arrayformula(regexextract(transpose(split(regexreplace(regexreplace(concatenate(IMPORTXML(Sheet2!A1,"//script")),"\n",""),"(^.*""ProfilePage"": \[{""user"": {""username"": "")(.*)(nodes.*)","$2"),", """,false)),"(^.*)"": .*")),arrayformula(regexextract(transpose(split(regexreplace(regexreplace(concatenate(IMPORTXML(Sheet2!A1,"//script")),"\n",""),"(^.*""ProfilePage"": \[{""user"": {""username"": "")(.*)(nodes.*)","$2"),", """,false)),"^.*"": (.*)"))},"[""}{]","")))
```

I ended up using a literal array so that I could effectively split the field names from the values , obviously you can format however you really want , but see the image here that demonstrates the fields it pulls:

[image]

ALso note that  the followers, followed_by, and media: count are the fields your mentioned (e.g. # of posts is called media count) and then the biography of course is self explanatory

Update: In answer to your comment - if you want to get the other 2 values out you can do it either in a single regexextract function like this:

If you using the raw import data these regexes work:

Media count:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(concatenate(IMPORTDATA(E1)),"""media: {""count"": (\d+)page_info: {")
```

Biography:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(concatenate(IMPORTDATA(E1)),"biography: ""(.*)""full_name")
```

If your using the importxml method these work:

`=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"biography"": ""(.*)"", "".*""media"": {""count"": (\d+), ""page_info""")`

That creates 2 capture groups which automatically puts them into their own adjacent cells, or you can do them individually which is:

and for biography:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"biography"": ""(.*)"", "".*""media")
```

media count:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"media"": {""count"": (\d+), ""page_info""")
```

Comment: I  used your more simpler formula to fetch "following" and "followers" data

1. followed_by

`code`=REGEXREPLACE(CONCATENATE(IMPORTDATA(B1)),"(^.*followed_by: {""count"": )(\d+)(}.*)","$2")

2. follows
`code`=REGEXREPLACE(CONCATENATE(IMPORTDATA(B1)),"(^.*follows: {""count"": )(\d+)(}.*)","$2")

Can you help me with similar small formula for "media count" and "biography" ?

Comment: Thanks Again @aurielle it's working perfectly fine for me.

Comment: this is awesome @AuriellePerlmann, is there an easy way to get the data in columns instead of rows

Comment: Yeah just wrap the whole thing in transpose () @krisrak

Comment: @AndrewAnderson probably because instagram has changed the way their api etc works also after the facebook issue with cambridge analytics